# Django progress bar

Tags: python, django

I'm using Django to upload a file and kick of an ETL job using

```
subprocess
```

The job takes roughly 15 seconds to run, and rather than having the user think the page is frozen, I'd like to show a [progress bar](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/components.html#progress).

I can figure out the AJAX to update the progress bar, but what I don't know how to do is return an HttpResponse while subprocess is running.  Perhaps threading is the solution?  I don't have any experience there.  Can someone give me some guidance?

Here's the view:

```
def start_job(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UploadForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid() and form.is_multipart():
            save_file(form.cleaned_data['file'])
            subprocess.call(["Kitchen.bat", "/file:job.kjb"])
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/success/')
    else:
        form = UploadForm()
    return render_to_response('template.html')
```

Comment: Hi There, what are you using to serve django? If you are working on NGINX you may have to install it via sudo apt-get install nginx-extras and configure it in order to have a correct progress upload feedback.

Comment: If you want a systematic solution take a look at [django-celery](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-celery). Also django devserver is not capable of threads but there is a [solution](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201103/quick_and_dirty_multithreaded_django_dev_server.html).

Comment: I'm using Apache to serve it.  I'll take a look at django-celery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks @Bula, [django-celery](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-celery) is the perfect solution.

Here's a good [introductory video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WevtkoCA-KQ) to get started.